# Python int overflows when calling ctypes functions

Tags: python, ctypes, ffi

I am toying with ctypes… I have the following C code

**Edit**: The reason I'm trying to figure this out is to make [this blog post](http://jiaaro.com/python-performance-the-easyish-way) more correct

sumrange.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

long sumrange(long);

long sumrange(long arg)
{
    long i, x;
    x = 0L;

    for (i = 0L; i < arg; i++) {
        x = x + i;
    }
    return x;
}
```

which I compile using the following command (on OSX)

```
$ gcc -shared -Wl,-install_name,sumrange.so -o ./sumrange.so -fPIC ./sumrange.c
```

I've implemented the same function in python:

```
pysumrange = lambda arg: sum(xrange(arg))
```

Then I run both at the interactive shell:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> sumrange = ctypes.CDLL('./sumrange.so')
>>> pysumrange = lambda arg: sum(xrange(arg))
>>> print sumrange.sumrange(10**8), pysumrange(10**8)
... 887459712 4999999950000000
```

…and the numbers don't match. Why would this be?

I tried using `unsigned long long` for all the variables in the C code with no effect (same output).

Comment: For your blog post, I used a numpy version and it falls nicely between Python and C.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522055/error-when-unload-a-64bit-dll-using-ctypes-windll

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`long` is a 32-bit type, so the C code simply overflows.

Python doesn’t; `pysumrange` gives you the correct answer.

`ctypes` doesn’t know that the function’s return type is `unsigned long long` unless you tell it. See [return types](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#return-types) in the Python standard library documentation. It says:

> By default functions are assumed to return the C `int` type. Other return types can be specified by setting the `restype` attribute of the function object.

So perhaps doing this, just before calling the function, will work for you:

```
sumrange.sumrange.restype = ctypes.c_ulonglong
```

Comment: It is good practice to also set the argtypes for a ctypes function.  `sumrange.sumrange.argtypes = [ctypes.c_long]`