# error when unload a 64bit dll using ctypes windll

Tags: python, 64-bit, ctypes

i found there are several posts here about unloading a dll using ctypes, and i followed exactly the way said to be working
from ctypes import *

```
file = CDLL('file.dll')

# do some stuff here

handle = file._handle # obtain the DLL handle

windll.kernel32.FreeLibrary(handle)
```

however, i am on python 64 bit and my dll is also compiled for x64, and i got an error from the last line above saying:

```
argument 1: <class 'OverflowError'>: int too long to convert
```

and i checked the handle to be a long int (int64) of '8791681138688', so does that mean windll.kernel32 only deals with int32 handle? Google search shows kernal32 is also for 64bit windows. how should i deal with this then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`FreeLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) takes a handle, defined as a C `void *` pointer. Refer to [Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751). Set this in the function pointer's `argtypes`:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)    
kernel32.FreeLibrary.argtypes = [wintypes.HMODULE]
```

The default conversion of a Python `int` or `long` (renamed `int` in Python 3) is to a C `long`, which is subsequently cast to a C `int`. Microsoft uses a 32-bit `long` even on 64-bit Windows, which is why the conversion raises `OverflowError`.

On platforms that have a 64-bit `long` (i.e. pretty much every other 64-bit OS), passing a pointer as a Python integer without defining the function's `argtypes` may actually segfault the process. The initial conversion to `long` works fine because it's the same size as a pointer. However, subsequently casting to a 32-bit C `int` may silently truncate the value.

Comment: and then `kernel32.FreeLibrary(handle)`, not `windll.kernel32.FreeLibrary(handle)`, right?

Comment: @endolith, yes, this defines the prototype on the `FreeLibrary` function pointer that's cached on `kernel32`. It's best to avoid the `windll` loader since it's global and can lead to clashes between packages for common shared libraries such as kernel32.dll.