# Python does not print long long integer correctly when calling a C library using ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes, long-integer

I want to do some Python multithreading and bypass the GIL using ctypes.

I wrote some C code, test.c:

```
long long sum_range(long high)
{
  long i;
  long long s = 0LL;
 
  for (i = 0L; i < high; i++)
      s += (long long)i;

  return s;
}
```

Compile and link using

```
gcc -O3 -g -fPIC -c -o test.o test.c
ld -shared -o libtest.so test.o
```

Call it from a Python 3 script:

```
import ctypes
import os

testlib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(os.getcwd()+"/libtest.so")

sum_range = testlib.sum_range
sum_range.argtypes = [ctypes.c_long]
sum_range.restypes = ctypes.c_longlong

iterations=100000

print("sum_range(iterations) = {}".format(sum_range(iterations)))
```

This gives

> sum_range(iterations) = 704982704

Instead of 4999950000.
What is wrong here?

PS Adding a `printf` to the C code shows that the correct value of 4999950000 is being returned to the Python script.

PPS The correct value is printed when `iterations` is e.g. ten times smaller, so 10000.

PPPS A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394616/python-int-overflows-when-calling-ctypes-functions) was raised earlier but setting restypes apparently does not fix the problem.

Comment: Should that be `sum_range.restype` instead of `sum_range.restypes`? I'm not familiar with ctypes at all, but the answer you linked to uses `restype` and not `restypes`.

Comment: That's it! Thanks. It should be restype (singular) and argtypes is plural. 
Does not make complete sense to me since a C library can return multiple values.
Also weird that no error is raised when using restypes (plural).

Comment: A function in C or Python can only return a single value. That might be a struct in C or a tuple/list in Python, but it's still a single value. No error was raised because the `sum_range` object probably has a `__dict__` that lets you set arbitrary attributes (this is by default for python types). Search for "\_\_dict\_\_" on the [data model page](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value.